# Distinction of different types of missing values is lost after importing data from SPSS into R

Tags: r, missing-data, spss

I've got a file containing survey data in SPSS. There are 3 types of missing values defined: invalid (coded as 900), not applicable (990), not filled in (999).
After importing the SPSS file into R using haven library, all types are coded as "NA", the distinction is lost.
How do you deal with this if distinction is important?

Comment: So in SPSS the „missings“ are encoded as numerical values? Why don‘t you export from SPSS with the numeric values, e.g. as CSV, and read the CSV (again with numeric) into R